# How to attach an image when creating an JIRA issue by using JIRA REST APIs

Tags: jquery, ajax, jira, jira-rest-api

I want to create an issue in JIRA through `JIRA REST API`s.

My question is how to send an (base64) image with the request for a new JIRA ?

Is there any parameter like for other fields (summary, description) or some other way to send the encoded image?

My Request from jQuery function as below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://jira.example.com/rest/api/2/issue/',  
    Content-Type: 'application/json',   
    data:
        {
            "fields": {
                 "project":{
                    "key": "TEST"
                 },
            "summary": 'testCaseName',
            "description": 'description',
            "priority": {
                "name": 'Trivial'
            },
            "issuetype": {
                 "name": "Bug"
            }
        }
    },
         dataType:"html",                                                                 
    success: function() {
        alert("success");
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});
```

Send Enceoded(image in the format of base64) with this request is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [JIRA documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Attaching+a+Screenshot)

> ## Attaching a Screenshot
>
> JIRA allows you to attach screenshots to an issue.
>
> This feature is only available if:
>
> - Your JIRA administrator has file attachments enabled (you also need the Create Attachments permission in the appropriate projects),
> - You are using a Windows or Mac client (if you use another operating system, you can attach a screenshot using the file attachment feature
>   instead, or for Linux users please see our article for enabling this
>   feature)
>
> Browser compatibility notes: If you are using Internet Explorer
> versions 8-10, the computer you are using will need to be running Java
> version 1.7+ platform. If you are using Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox
> or Internet Explorer 11, the screenshot capability takes advantage of
> HTML5 compatibility. Safari is not supported.

**EDIT**

To do it with `JIRA REST APIs` instead:

```
curl -D- -u admin:admin -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@das.txt" http://localhost:8082/jira1/rest/api/2/issue/MP-1/attachments
```

obiously changing your username, password, jira instance, filename accordingly.

Source: directly stolen [from here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/167366/how-do-i-upload-attachment-to-jira-issue-via-rest-api).

Comment: And ? What is your problem ? I've seen now you've tagged the question `jira-rest-api` too. Are you trying to attach an image via rest-api ?

Comment: Yes , AS seen in the request of creating issue via rest api there are some parameters like description,summary ,key. So, which parameter is used for sending base64 with this request?